# Fast API password verification error not showing properly

Tags: python, authentication, fastapi

Trying to perform a simple auth transaction with Fast API. When the user logs in, I want to return an error if the password length is less than 6, and I do this as follows.

```
class AuthSchema(BaseModel):
    email: str
    password: constr(min_length=6)

    @validator("password")
    def validate_password(cls, value):
        if len(value) < 6:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Password must be at least 6 characters long")
        return value


@router.post("/login", response_model=CustomResponse)
async def login_user(user: AuthSchema, db: Session = Depends(db.get_session)):
    try:
        if not UserServices().verify_user_password(db, user.email, user.password):
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                detail="Invalid credentials"
            )
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail=str(e)
        )
    token = token_services.create_access_token({
        "id": user.id,
        "role": user.role
    })
    return CustomResponse(
        message="User logged in successfully",
        data={
            "token": token
        },
        status=200
    )
```

The code is like this but the error it returns is as follows

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "type": "string_too_short",
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "password"
      ],
      "msg": "String should have at least 6 characters",
      "input": "123",
      "ctx": {
        "min_length": 6
      },
      "url": "https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/string_too_short"
    }
  ]
}
```

what is the reason of this. Or is there another way to return this error? Thank you for your answers.

pydantic==2.6.3
fastapi==0.110.0

Comment: It is returning that because the field is constrained. Is this not what you want?

Comment: The type is validated before your validator gets called, so your custom validator never gets called. It should also not raise a HTTPException as that is specific to your use case, but probably a ValueError instead (or something similar). If you want to access any fields before validation happens, you need to use a `before` validator: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/validators/#before-after-wrap-and-plain-validators

Comment: @MatsLindh 
Thank you for your answer, I looked at the documentation a little bit and frankly I didn't understand much :) so I decided to try something like this:

`@app.post("/register/", dependencies=[Depends(validate_password_length)])`

Answer (score 0):

You have `constr(min_length=6)` constraint in your AuthSchema model. When fastapi converts http request body to model, it waits for `ValueError` exception from pydantic. Upon receiving this exception fastapi converts it to an `HTTPException` meaning it sends a response with code 422 without even executing your code. If you want to call your own error, just remove the `constr` constraint like

```
class AuthSchema(BaseModel):
    email: str
    password: str
```

And check the length of password in `UserService` method